# Is there any way to see the last 100 elements inside a variable in PyCharm debugger?

Tags: python, pycharm

When debugging with PyCharm, a variable list has more than 1000 data. When I go to see the value, the system just displays the first 100 data, I need to double click to see the next 100.

Is there any way to see all the data at once, or is there any way to let me see the last 100?

Comment: Run the same code in`python console` print variable.

Comment: You can open evaluate expression (Alt+F8 default) in debug mode and enter list_name[-100:].

Answer (score 0):

Open *Debug* window and in *Variables* panel click `+` *(New Watch...)* or press <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Type `variable_name[-100:]`.
That will let you see last 100 elements.

If variable is not a list an error `{TypeError}'int' object is not subscriptable` will be displayed instead.

Also unlike *Evaluate Expression command*, variables added to *Watches* persist from one debug session to another.